# Scipy crashes on Win64

Tags: python, scipy, python-2.6, win64

I'm trying to use the scipy package in my 32-bit Python 2.6 on 64-bit Windows 7.

I have installed Scipy 0.12.0 from the 32-bit Python Superpack binary installer. The installation went through smoothly, but after completion, I'm encountering a crash every time I try to use it in any other way than just importing the whole package - either running the test (`scipy.test()`) or importing one of its submodules. When I just import the whole package, it generates a warning:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py:89: UserWarning: Numpy 1.5.0 or above is recommended for this version of scipy (detected version 1.3.0) UserWarning)
```

Numpy that came together with it runs and tests (`numpy.test()`) flawlessly. Python works fine as well.

The Python I'm using came together with an ESRI ArcGIS 10.0 installation and is the only version supported by it, so I can't modify it.

Any suggestions?
Thanks, Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS 10.0 includes numpy 1.3.0, which is not compatible with any recent scipy binaries. Try [scipy 0.7.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.7.1/), which was released around the same time (July 2009) as numpy 1.3.0.